# elasticsearch query string(full text search) which can't be searched

Tags: elasticsearch

we have a document below. I can't searched with financialmarkets. but it can be searched with industry_icon_financialmarkets.png. Can anyone tell me what is the reason?

content is the text type field.

document:

```
{
    "title":"test",
    "content":"industry_icon_financialmarkets.png"
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "from": 0,  
  "size": 2,
  "query": {  
    "bool": {  
      "must": [  
        {  
          "query_string": {  
            "query": "\"industry_icon_financialmarkets.png\""
          }  
        }  
      ]  
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any mapping for the above fields?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the underscore when ES indexes?

Comment: Hi Rakkiasamy, the mapping is content": {"type": "text"}, I want to es can understand financialmarket is a word.

Answer (score 0):

The default analyzer for text field is `standard` which won't break `industry_icon_financialmarkets` into tokens using `_` as a delimiter. I would suggest you to use `simple` analyzer instead which will breaks text into terms whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter.

You can also add sub-field of type `keyword` to retain the original value.

So the mapping of the field should be:

```
{
   "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "simple",
      "fields": {
         "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of creating index, we should have our own mapping for each fields based on its type to get the expected result.

Mapping

```
PUT relevance
{"mapping":{"ID":{"type":"long"},"title": 
{"type":"keyword","analyzer":"my_analyzer"},
"content": 
 {"type":"string","analyzer":"my_analyzer","search_analyzer":"my_analyzer"}},
"settings":
 {"analysis":
  {"analyzer":
   {"my_analyzer": 
   {"tokenizer":"my_tokenizer"}},
    "tokenizer":
     {"my_tokenizer": 
      {"type":"ngram","min_gram":3,"max_gram":30,"token_chars": 
      ["letter","digit"]
      }
     }
   },"number_of_shards":5,"number_of_replicas":2
  }
 }
```

Then start inserting documents,

```
POST relevance/_doc/1
{
 "name": "1elastic",
  "content": "working fine" //replace special characters with space using program before inserting into ES index.
}
```

Query

```
  GET relevance/_search
  {"size":20,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"content": 
  {"query":"fine","fuzziness":1}}}]}}}
```